# ng-2 charts moment js dependency

Tags: angular, size, momentjs, ng2-charts

Hi I am trying to reduce the bundle size of my angular application as much as possible when I noticed moment.js was taking up 500kb of space when Im not even using time/date formats.
[bundle sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2qNl.png)

It appears that by installing ng-2 yarn installs chart.js as a dependency with moment.js as a dependency of chart,js. Does anyone know how to remove this dependency?

Comment: Just FYI - chart.js 2.8 will probably not depend on any library for time, and will allow a pluggable adapter for whatever library you wish to use in your enclosing project (or no adapter at all if no time scales are needed) - See this issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5960